# Python max and min of records with same attributes

Tags: python

I am working with a list or a dictionary I gathered from a csv file. What I would like to do is write out a new csv file with the MAX and MIN values associated with particular attributes, e.g.:

```
field1 field2 field3
1      hi     1
2      hi     5
3      bye    2
4      bye    7
```

Should be listed by the attribute in `field2` in the new csv file as:

```
f1  f2   min   max
1   hi    1     5
2   bye   2     7
```

My data structures is pretty weak but I have attempted a couple of different ways including reading it from the csv file. I thought there may be a way to find it easily if I put the data into a dictionary or a list, as long as I can output it to a csv file when I find the min and max.

Here is what I have tried. I think it's an algorithm issue. The bottom code works for me but I do not know when they do not equal anymore so I am not sure when to put it in the csv file as min; when is the list complete?

***First attempt:***

```
dict_rows = {}
frames = []
lines = (line.strip() for line in open(csvFile))
reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
i = 0
for rec in reader:
    #print rec
    dict_rows[i] = (rec[1],rec[5])
    i += 1


##    for key in dict_rows[1]:
##        if dict_rows[key]>max:
##            max = d[key]


##        if d[1] == d[1]:
##            print d
##            print "equal"
    print dict_rows

max_value = max(dict_rows.values())
min_value = min(dict_rows.values())
print max_value
print min_value
```

***This seemed to be closer though:***

```
   prev_line = None
lines = (line.strip() for line in open(csvFile))
##    for line in lines:
##        print prev_line,line
##        prev_line = line
reader = csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
i = 1
frames = []
x = bool
for line in reader:
    print '%s) %s ' %(i,line)
    #print 'Previous: %s \n Current: %s' %(prev_line, line)

    #print '%s) %s ' %(prev_line,line)
##        if i == 1:
##           print 'First line header'
##           next_line = reader.next()
    if prev_line != None:
##            if prev_line[1] != line[1]:
##                print '%i) Does NOT %s != %s ?' %(i, prev_line[1],line[1])
            if prev_line[1] == line[1]:
            print '%i) EQUAL! %s == %s' %(i, prev_line[1],line[1])

            num = line[5]
            frames.append(num)
            x = True


        else:
            print '%i) Does NOT %s != %s ?' %(i, prev_line[1],line[1])
            frames = []
            x = False

    prev_line = line
    if x == True:
        min_frame = min(frames)
        max_frame = max(frames)
    else:
        min_frame = 0
        max_frame = 0
    print min_frame
    print max_frame



    else:
        next_line = reader.next()
        print 'Next: %s' % next_line[1]
        print '%i) Does %s == %s == %s ?' %(i, prev_line[1],line[1],next_line[1])

        if line[1] != next_line[1]:
            print '%i) %s != %s' %(i, line[1],next_line[1])

        elif line[1] != next_line:
            print '%i) Does not! %s != %s' %(i, line[1],next_line[1])


    i +=1
```

Comment: Please cleanup your examples.

Comment: still needs quite a lot of cleanup. It's quite a mess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
data={}
with open(fn) as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
    header=next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        data.setdefault(row[1], []).append(int(row[2]))

print 'key\tmin\tmax'    
for k in data.keys():
    print '{}\t{}\t{}'.format(k, min(data[k]), max(data[k]))
```

With your example data, prints:

```
key min max
bye 2   7
hi  1   5
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking but did not know how to implement it thank you! Also for looking past my shoddy attempt and taking the time to read what I was trying to do :). You saved me painful hours against a wall.

Answer (score 0):

maybe something like this

```
dict_rows = {}
lines = (line.strip() for line in open(csvFile))
for line in csv.reader(lines, delimiter='\t', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE):
    key = line[1]
    value = line[5]
    prev = dict_rows.get(key, (value, value))
    dict_rows[key] = (min(prev[0], value), max(prev[1], value))
for key, value in dict_rows.items():
    print key, value[0], value[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

use pandas. here's a sample

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
df.groupby('field2').agg([np.min, np.max]).to_csv(out_filename)
```